# Modify Output Cache Depending On Date Found in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I know I can create a custom outputcache attribute for ASP.NET MVC controller action.  I would like to change the duration of the output cache depending on if an event has passed or not.  If it has passed the current date then the duration would be alot longer.  However I need to check a database to do this, however I am making the same call within the controller action itself.  Is there anyway to set the duration at the end of the action result so it's dependent on the date of the event that was queried inside the controller action?  I dont want to make two calls, one in the output cache attribute and controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should utilize the `SqlCacheDependency` class for that, for example:

**VIEW:**

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" SqlDependency="Northwind:Employees" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

**WEB.CONFIG:**

```
 <caching>
      <sqlCacheDependency enabled = "true" pollTime = "60000" >
        <databases>
          <add name="northwind" 
            connectionStringName="Northwind"
            pollTime="9000000"
            />
        </databases>
      </sqlCacheDependency>
    </caching>
```

The above example shows an ASP.NET Web.config file that enables table-based dependencies on a SQL Server database table.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more, can this work with Entity Framework?

Comment: sql dependencies is nothing to do with EF. It's everything to do with the SQL server. For pre-2005 servers, ASP.net polls a table in the SQL server for changes. when you make a change you update this table, probably using triggers. for >= 2005, it uses native changing tracking in the SQL Server to tell asp.net something changed.

Comment: @MikeFlynn I hope Simon Halsey's comment helped you.

Comment: I assume it can work with a multiple join table also.  Guess I need to read up on it.